# Changing 3D-numpy array last values based on condition of first 3 values

Tags: python, numpy

For example a RGBA numpy 3D array:

```
arr1 = numpy.random.randint(256, size = (3,3,4))
```

[R,G,B,A] is an element in the last axis.

Now, I am to set A to 0 when R, G and B are all 0.

How to achieve this by using numpy `where` method? or any fast method? Basically I am trying to avoid nested loop due to speed concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the rows where the condition (*"R, G and B are all 0"*) is `True` on the axis `2`, to reassign the last column the needed value:

```
arr[(arr[:, :, :-1] == 0).all(2), -1] = 0
```

Comment: this is so cool